# efeito em attr.('style JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, javascript-eventos

Preciso executar esse filtro 'grayscale' de forma gradativa, que vá aplicando aos poucos gradualmente em um período de tempo.

```
$('#backstatic').attr('style', 'filter: grayscale(100%)');
```

essa é a minha linha, gostaria de saber se tem como definir o tempo para que o efeito do filtro se aplique porém de forma gradual.

Comment: Eu vi que você já conseguiu mas não seria melhor assim? `$('#backstatic').css('filter', 'grayscale(100%)');` Porque eu acho que isso estaria errado

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi assim:

```
$('#backstatic').attr('style', 'filter: grayscale(100%);transition: 2s');
```

Descobri que adicionando o style de transição do css3 também funciona!

então onde está **'transition:'** o **'2s'** é o tempo.